# How do I remove the mouse battery indicator?

Tags: mouse, battery, settings

I just upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and it seems there has been a new notification/status bar thingy (sorry I'm new to Ubuntu) for my mouse battery. It is in the place where it normally tells me how much laptop battery time/charge I have left. If I click on it, I can see the laptop battery status.

I want to disable the info for the mouse and only display for my laptop battery. How do I do this?

Comment: Yeah, I'll be waiting here too for an answer. It doesn't properly detect mine, just says esitmating....

Comment: It seems there was an update? It now displays the battery time and percentage by default, but if you click on it, it shows the mouse battery stuff. Technically not a fix, but all I really want to see is the laptop battery info.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is a known issue, I'm not certain if there is a definitive way. Do you have laptop-mode-tools installed?

You can wait for it to be fixed, that's all I really know.